# Pyinstaller: path or glob "/usr/include/python3.4m/pyconfig.h" not found or matches no files."

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am trying to build my project on a Oracle virtualbox ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

My project is in Python 34. I installed pyinstaller via:

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/python3.zip
```

When I run `pyinstaller run.py` I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: Path or glob "/usr/include/python3.4m/pyconfig.h" not found or matches no files.
```

I indeed don't have a directory '/usr/include/python3.4m', only 'usr/include/python2.7'. Python 34 is installed (by default in Ubuntu).

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently installing `libpython3.4-dev` package solved the problem.
http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/amd64/libpython3.4-dev/filelist

So do `sudo apt-get install libpython3.4-dev` if you encounter the problem.

Comment: My error was similiar, and executing `sudo apt-get install libpython2.7-dev` did the trick. Thanks.